# How to open twitter main activity from android programmatically?

Tags: android, twitter

I want to open twitter main activity twitter application if app is exist on phone. How can I do this?

I found these codes. But It opens user profile activity

`try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=USERID"));
    startActivity(intent);
 } catch (Exception e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com")));
 }`

Thanks for helps..

Answer (score 0):

You should query [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) and check if the application exists or check if that intent can be interpreted on the device. If it exists, launch the intent. Otherwise whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/"));
intent.setPackage("com.twitter.android");